# deserializeUser not called in passport.js when use local login

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

i have problem that deserializeUser is not called.
so i checked session file, and there was no passport object
that mean when i use serializeUser, passport object is not stored in session file

this is my code deserializeUser is not called.
when i use this code

```
app.post('/auth/login',  
  passport.authenticate(
      'local',  
      {
          successRedirect: '/welcome',    
          failureRedirect: '/auth/login', 
          failureFlash: false 
      }
  )
)
```

but if i use this code it works ...!!!

```
app.post('/auth/login',  
  passport.authenticate(
      'local',  
      {
          //successRedirect: '/welcome',    
          failureRedirect: '/auth/login', 
          failureFlash: false 
      }
  )
  ,
  function(req, res){
      req.session.save(function(){
          res.redirect('/welcome');
      });
  }
)
```

what is difference when use req.session.save in this case